# Alternative to using property files for enviroment settings of Java EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, properties, configuration, websphere, jndi

Am working on thick clients java application which has stored environment related data (like mail details, DB connection password ) in properties file.

If properties file are missing while application trying to load, its need to send a fatal mail. but in order to send mail, it needs properties file. because it contains the all the mail details. Since properties file are missing it causing big issue.

So Kindly suggest me the alternative way for properties file except in java code.

Is it possible to store a properties file in websphere ?

Comment: You may set system properties on the administration console.

Answer (score 1):

In WebSphere Application Server this is accomplished through the use of `Resource Environment Entry`. You need to do the following:

1. Create an implementation of `javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` that reads properties from JNDI.
   The basic code might look like this:

   ```
   public Object getObjectInstance(Object object, Name name, Context nameCtx, Hashtable<?, ?> environment) throws Exception {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       Reference ref = (Reference) object;
       Enumeration addrs = ref.getAll();

       while (addrs.hasMoreElements()) {
           RefAddr addr = (RefAddr) addrs.nextElement();
           String entryName = addr.getType();
           String value = (String) addr.getContent();
           properties.setProperty(entryName, value);
       }
       return properties;
   }
   ```
2. Register the implementation class as `Resource Environment Provider` within the server. Follow the steps described in [New Resource environment provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/uree_resenvpronew.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0&lang=en).
3. Define `Resource Environment Entry` and bind it to the newly registered provider – [Resource environment entry settings](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_resenventent1.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0&lang=en)
4. In the entry create custom properties that you need.
5. Bind `Resource Environment Entry` to Java EE module in your application – this can be done in different ways and depends on the type of the module.

If you need more details there is a comprehensive guide here – [Using resource environment providers in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0611_totapally/0611_totapally.html). If you are using WAS 7.0 or higher there is no need to put the provider in a shared library – it can reside directly in the application.

As for storing credentials, there is a special facility for this – `J2C Authentication Alias`, as noted by [Gas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3701228/gas).

Answer (score 0):

You can always have defaults for your applications properties, so this might be a solution for a mail configuration, provided there is a fixed default.

An alternative is to use application properties stored in a database. Of course this requires to have a database connection (but which is common to have in a persistence configuration of your application or container).

As already said in [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413093/ejb-properties-file/24424287#24424287), We use this technique in all our web applications, mainly for two reasons:

1. Changes to a property can be done during runtime without monitoring file changes, they can be done by the application itself and one does not need to know a path outside of the deployed application.
2. Properties can have additional information, such as a type (e.g. number, date, string), a default value, a comment or a user who changed it.

For implementing it, you'll create an application-scoped component which accesses the database properties for the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could store string properties in JNDI tree via console (Environment > Naming > Name space bining) and then access them via InitialContext.

But for resources like database or mail server, you should rather create DataSource, J2C Authentication alias or MailSession entry and then map it to application resources during application installation.